# Finding external disks in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 using WSL.
Sometimes I use Windows programs (Word, etc.) and sometimes Linux programs, particularly the Ubuntu terminal window.

I can find my files on "Local disk (c:)" using Windows File Explorer in Windows.  I can also find the same drive using `/mnt/c/Users/<username>` in the Ubuntu terminal.  I can access such files either from both Windows apps and from Ubuntu.

However, when I have an external drive (`E:` in Windows Explorer), I cannot find it in WSL/Ubuntu.  I see `/mnt/e`, but not the files on it.  In other words, I can:

- Write files to `E:` using Windows applications
- Write files to `/mnt/e` using in Ubuntu (e.g. using cat)

But the ones I create in Windows I cannot see in Ubuntu and vice versa.

Where does the mounted disk turn up in the unix-style path notation and vice versa?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I understand your question, and I've rewritten it to be more clear to others using the actual product names.  If I have misunderstood anything, please re-edit and fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I found out what you need to do.  You have to explicitly mount the disk at /mnt/e.  How to do this is explained at https://superuser.com/questions/1114341/windows-10-ubuntu-bash-shell-how-do-i-mount-other-windows-drives

Comment: Right. I was just about to answer it after editing, but you deleted it just then, so I figured you had found the answer.  No worries if you want to delete it again!